# FATAL EXCEPTION - on calling recognize() Google Speech API Android

Tags: java, android, google-speech-api

I'm trying to run Google Speech API on android. I want to use asynchronous method as I want to load a file and convert it to text.

On calling ***recgognize()*** it throws 'FATAL EXCEPTION'

**code :**

```
RecognizeResponse response;
    recognitionConfig = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
            .setLanguageCode("en-US")
            .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
            .setSampleRateHertz(DEFAULT_SAMPLING_RATE)
            .build();

    try {
        SpeechGrpc.SpeechBlockingStub speechClient = getSpeechBlockingStub();
        RecognitionAudio recognitionAudio = RecognitionAudio
                .newBuilder()
                .setContent(audioBytes)
                .build();
        RecognizeRequest request = RecognizeRequest
                .newBuilder()
                .setConfig(recognitionConfig)
                .setAudio(recognitionAudio)
                .build();

        response = speechClient.recognize(request);

        if ((response.getResultsCount() == 0) || (response.getResults(0).getAlternativesCount() == 0)) {
            //throw new AIServiceException("No speech");
        }
        String transcript = response.getResults(0).getAlternatives(0).getTranscript();

        Toast.makeText(cntxt, transcript, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException | StatusRuntimeException e) {
        //throw new AIServiceException("Failed to recognize speech", e);
    }
```

**Error:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: com.inc.pixie.arron, PID: 7938
>                                                                      java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService io.grpc.internal.ClientTransportFactory.getScheduledExecutorService()"
>                                                                          at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.getScheduledExecutorService(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:52)
>                                                                          at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:557)
>                                                                          at io.grpc.auth.ClientAuthInterceptor.interceptCall(ClientAuthInterceptor.java:65)
>                                                                          at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
>                                                                          at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:536)
>                                                                          at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:113)
>                                                                          at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechGrpc$SpeechBlockingStub.recognize(SpeechGrpc.java:241)
>                                                                          at com.inc.pixie.arron.RecognizeAPI.voiceRequest(RecognizeAPI.java:89)
>                                                                          at com.inc.pixie.arron.ConversationActivity.onCreate(ConversationActivity.java:28)
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6674)
>                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2690)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2806)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1540)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6293)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1065)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)

What is wrong?

What does this mean - `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService io.grpc.internal.ClientTransportFactory.getScheduledExecutorService()"`

Answer (score -1):

From what i can see, the code above is not for aync request.

Here is the sample code async request
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-recognize
where the method used is longRunningRecognizeAsync

and referring to the above code for a sync request, have you tried the sample code on github from the project below ?
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/sync-recognize